# My partition is using negative space. Should I worry?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, storage, dual-boot

[image: disk]

As you can see, according to Disk Utility, I'm using negative space in /dev/disk0s7. This is obviously incorrect, however, I am slightly worried as to what this may mean for the partition's effects on the other parts of the disk. For the sake of completeness, here is the output of `diskutil list`:

```
vtc:~ vtcakavsmoace$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS MAIN                    124.9 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data                         62.0 GB    disk0s4
   5:                 Linux Swap                         1.0 GB     disk0s5
   6:           Linux Filesystem                         60.0 GB    disk0s6
   7:       Microsoft Basic Data STUFFS                  2.1 GB     disk0s7
```

`gpt`:

```
vtc:~ vtcakavsmoace$ sudo gpt -vvv show /dev/disk0
gpt show: /dev/disk0: mediasize=251000193024; sectorsize=512; blocks=490234752
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
gpt show: /dev/disk0: MBR part: type=175, start=411648, size=243849296
gpt show: /dev/disk0: MBR part: type=175, start=244260944, size=1269536
gpt show: /dev/disk0: MBR part: type=131, start=245530480, size=121093750
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B, start=40, size=409600
gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC, start=411648, size=243849296
gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC, start=244260944, size=1269536
gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7, start=245530480, size=121093750
gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=0657FD6D-A4AB-43C4-84E5-0933C84B4F4F, start=487964672, size=1998848
gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, start=366624768, size=117145600
gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7, start=483770368, size=4194304
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Sec GPT at sector 490234751
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         MBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640       2008         
     411648  243849296      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  244260944    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  245530480  121093750      4  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  366624230        538         
  366624768  117145600      6  GPT part - 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4
  483770368    4194304      7  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  487964672    1998848      5  GPT part - 0657FD6D-A4AB-43C4-84E5-0933C84B4F4F
  489963520     271199         
  490234719         32         Sec GPT table
  490234751          1         Sec GPT header
```

Should I be worried?

Comment: If you select the volume with the Finder and select "Get Info" from the menu bar, what do you get. Really, I would not worry, the Disk Utility is riddled with gems like this.

Comment: Are you REALLY trying to use `FAT` on a 2.15GB drive? If you must use FAT at least use `FAT32`. `FAT` has many limitations on capacity.

Comment: @DavidAnderson It says it has 5 MB used. O.o Mostly, I just want to make sure that the computer wasn't trying to write to the partition and ended up writing over something else. That obviously isn't the case. :P